# DMProcessConfigXML is closing the running application if used for uninstallation in WM/CE platform

Tags: c++, process, windows-mobile, windows-ce, uninstallation

I have two apps which is installed in WM/CE device.

The installed applications are ***APP1.exe*** & ***APP2.exe***.

During installation of ***APP1*** & ***APP2*** the another process which is ***doJob.exe*** is stored in the respective folder of ***APP1*** & ***APP2***.

Basically ***APP1*** has his own directory & same applies for ***APP2***.

***Please note:***

1. ***APP1*** & ***APP2*** internally launches the above process ***doJob.exe***.
2. Both ***APP1*** & ***APP2*** is using the same name for running the another process internally i.e. ***doJob.exe***.

***What I Do:***

1. Only launching ***APP1*** which internally launches its associated process ***doJob.exe***.
2. From ***APP1.exe***, I call `DMProcessConfigXML` API for uninstalling the ***APP2***.
3. Doing so this should uninstall the complete stuff of ***APP2*** including the ***doJob.exe*** present under ***APP2*** directory.

***Observation:***

1. Calling **DMProcessConfigXML**, shuts down the ***doJob.exe*** associated with ***APP1*** while uninstalling the stuff of ***APP2***.

***Expected:***

1. It should not close the ***doJob.exe*** process associated with ***APP1***.

The code is shown below:-

```
void UninstallApp(){    
        wstring strRequest = 
         L"<wap-provisioningdoc><characteristic type=\"UnInstall\">"
         L"<characteristic type=\"\\Program Files\\APP2";
        strRequest += L"\">"
         L"<parm name=\"uninstall\" value=\"1\"/>"
            L"</characteristic>"
            L"</characteristic></wap-provisioningdoc>";

        LPFN_DMPROCESS_CONFIGXML_T lpfn_dmprocess_configxml = NULL; 
        HRESULT hr         = E_FAIL;
        LPWSTR wszOutput   = NULL;
        HMODULE hLib = LoadLibrary(TEXT("aygshell.dll"));
        if (hLib)
        {
            lpfn_dmprocess_configxml = (LPFN_DMPROCESS_CONFIGXML_T)GetProcAddress(hLib, L"DMProcessConfigXML");
            if (lpfn_dmprocess_configxml != NULL)
            {
                hr = lpfn_dmprocess_configxml(strRequest.c_str(), CFGFLAG_PROCESS, &wszOutput);
            }
        }

        if (hLib)
            FreeLibrary (hLib);

        if (FAILED(hr) || !wszOutput )
           MessageBox(NULL,L"Failed",L"Failed",MB_OK);

        if ( wszOutput )
          free( wszOutput );
}
```

***Not getting any clue. 
Please let me know, whether I need to change something in the XML property in the above code or this is a drawback of using DMProcessConfigXML API.***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the behavior of the WCELOAD program, which is the system program actually doing the uninstall behind the scenes.  See the Remarks section [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb158700.aspx) for more information.

> In Windows Mobile Version 5.0 and later, when using Wceload.exe to reinstall a .cab file, Wceload.exe uninstalls the previously installed version of the .cab file before installing the new version. **During the uninstallation portion of this process, Wceload.exe closes any currently running executables that were installed on the target device using a .cab file, based on their filename. Wceload.exe also closes any executables that are the target of a file operation, such as a move or a copy.** To close an executable, Wceload.exe sends WM_CLOSE to all top-level windows owned by the process. If the process does not exit in a timely manner after receiving the WM_CLOSE message, then Wceload.exe forcibly closes it by calling TerminateProcess. Wceload.exe does not attempt to close executables that are shipped in the run-time image on the target device.